# WordPress loop trough custom post types with children

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, custom-post-type

I'm tying to display the titles of the parent and related children of the custom post type named 'collection' in my global menu using:

```
<?php
 $loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'collection',
    'order_by' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',                                                                           
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent' => 0
) );
?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="large-2">
        <?php the_title(); ?> /* the parent title */

           /* show the related children */
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I want to show the children of the related parent underneath the parent title within the `large-2` class. I think another loop would work. Any ideas?

Comment: `'post_parent' => 0` makes the query return only top-level posts to begin with, so you'll need to remove that. After that, you can do it with two nested loops - in the outer one, you only output posts that have their parent post ID set to 0, and in the inner loop, you output only the posts that have the parent ID matching that of the current post from the outer loop.

Comment: _But_ - this likely won't work with the default WP looping mechanism, resp. you would have to pay real close attention to when & where the loop needs to be "reset". Doing your own `foreach` loops over `$loop->posts` (that's an array containing all the posts the query returned) will probably be easier - but then you won't be able to use "loop functions" such as `the_title` any more, you would have to switch to their equivalents that return the value (instead of outputting it directly), and take the post ID as parameter.